# Qualifier on Bean method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

Id, like to ask that what exactly a Qualifier annotation is doing on a Bean method? I thought it is the same as specifying a name inside the Bean annotation but a use-case proves otherwise:

The configuration:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("myGroup")
public MyObject myObject1() {
    return new MyObject("myObject1");
}


@Bean
@Qualifier("myGroup")
public MyObject myObject2() {
    return new MyObject("myObject2");
}

@Bean
public MyObject myObject3() {
    return new MyObject("myObject3");
}
```

The injection:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myGroup")
private List<MyObject> myObjects;
```

The list myObjects will contain only myObject1 and myObject2, the ones that have the qualifier.
The bean names will be named by the method.
So my question would be, why, and how is this working?

Comment: The proper usage is `@Bean("myGroup")` instead of `@Bean @Qualifier("myGroup")`

Answer (score 1):

This works because you're autowiring a list of `MyObject`. Autowiring multiple beans of the same class into a list containing that class is not an issue. I mean, it's different instances, yes but if you're autowiring a list of them then you should know why you're doing that.

If you do this then it won't work

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myGroup")
private MyObject myObjects;
```

because then `myObject1` and `myObject2` would both be qualified as autowiring candidate, which will throw Spring off. And since you put `@Qualifier` when autowiring, it only autowires beans that fit the *name* that's specified in the `@Qualifier`